# Constructing Datastructure with duplicate keys in a dict (but cannot use arrays)

Tags: python, soap, duplicates, suds

I am trying to send a SOAP request using Suds for the following data structure

```
<WriteRequest>
  <ClassName>Fifth_Grade</ClassName>
  <UpdateStudent>
    <StudentName>Andrew</StudentName>
    <StudentWeight>60</StudentWeight>
    <StudentName>Mike</StudentName>
    <StudentWeight>54</StudentWeight>
    <StudentName>Emma</StudentName>
    <StudentWeight>71</StudentWeight>
  </UpdateField>
</WriteRequest>
```

When I create a dict for UpdateSudent, the key value of StudentName and StudentWeight get overwritten on every iteration of assignment.

If I use arrays, the data structure submitted becomes an undesirable format like this

```
<UpdateStudent>
        <StudentName>Andrew</StudentName>
        <StudentWeight>60</StudentWeight>
</UpdateStudent>
<UpdateStudent>
       <StudentName>Mike</StudentName>
       <StudentWeight>54</StudentWeight>
</UpdateStudent>
```

Any thoughts on how best I can represent the first datastructure in python.

Thank you !!

Comment: Why don't you use one dictionary per UpdateStudent entry?

Comment: The writeRequest API is written in a way that only the entries under the first updateStudent are used. the rest are just ignored.